# Handling comments in code when doing i18n

Tags: internationalization, babeljs

I'm in the process of translating a Open Source project from Chinese to English, and I've used i18n (in this case babel) to separate the code from both English and Chinese translations.

Everything's done, except for a rather large number of inline comments in the code.

Obviously, babel can't translate comments inline (and it would be rather obnoxious if it did, anyway.  Since code would not be unique across languages and therefore less easily verifiable.)

The way I see it, there are a number of options:

1. **Leave comments in** -

   *Pro*: Helps original author, etc.

   *Con*: Makes it distracting for ongoing translation and anyone who doesn't speak the language
2. **Strip out all the comments** -

   *Pro*: Code is native-language-agnostic, so it makes sense.  Who needs comments anyway? Use the source, Luke!

   *Con*: Goes against SE principles.  Could lose something important in understanding how the code works - maybe something's been done to avoid a security risk, etc.
3. **Place English comments near Chinese comments**

   (Possibly moved to lines above and prefixed with "EN" and "ZH", for example).

   *Pro*: Best of both worlds, comments kept close to code

   *Con*: Not conducive to dictionary-style translation. Can get bulky with more languages.
4. **Create a comment dictionary / notes**

   *Pro*: Keeps the comments in a separate file for easy translation.

   *Con*: Difficult to keep synced with code.  Not intuitive to remember to update comments related to code when changing coe.
5. **Use a different preprocessor for i18n before/after each development cycle.**

   *Pro*: Comments et al would be in your language.  Could link this to git pull/push so you only ever see the code in your language.

   *Con*: Bulky, non-obvious process.  Could result in code-verification or even compilation errors.

None of these seem like really great solutions.

***If you do alot of this, and the code is shared publicly between developers who don't share a native tongue, is there a recommended way to handle translating (or not) comments in the code itself?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

It seems to be a mixture of:

2. *Strip out all the comments*, and
3. *Place English comments near Chinese comments*.

**Inline** comments are almost always trivial - **Strip them**

**Functional** comments are not as intrusive - **Translate them** (possibly with a i18n prefix e.g. "[cn]:" or "[en]:").

**Explanation**

My meagre amount of research tends to suggest that larger projects make strong attempts to reduce comments and let the code explain itself, instead focusing on code quality which reduces the need for comments.

e.g. From the [Linux Kernel Coding guidelines](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle):

> NEVER try to explain HOW your code works in a comment: it's much
>   better to write the code so that the **working** is obvious, and it's
>   a waste of time to explain badly written code.

...and from the [MySQL coding standards](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/commenting-code.html):

> Comment your code when you do something that someone else may think is
>   not trivial.

Both of these standards (and others) recommend minimal function descriptions also, so that's not as obtrusive to understanding the code, and, since function descriptions are generally multi-lined and above the code itself, multiple languages can be included as necessary.

Maybe someone, somewhere has built an interface that can isolate comments into the readers language, but I couldn't (yet) find any that do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand... You say you separated the code from the languages part. So now you should have code (with comments) + English resources + Chinese resources (i used resources for whatever your programming language use to store localizable content)

Translators only see the resources, not the code, nor the comments. The comments stay untranslated, for the developers.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.  Yes, the question states I'm talking about the "with comments" part.  Since the original developers speak chinese, the comments are in chinese, but I don't speak chinese, so I need to translate the comments as well as the code.  Each developer going forward also may speak a different language.  Surely we don't expect code to be maintained only by people who share the same language?

Answer (score 0):

I always think that API comments exported in the project and private comments in open source projects should be internationalized, which is very convenient for developers in other countries.

On Github, there are actually many developers who use their own national language to comment on some well-known open source projects and some of their own annotations. Most of the reason is that if they do not translate, the efficiency of developers reading comments very low.

Similar to `.d.ts` in TypeScript, I think function annotation translation can also take a similar form, which is more convenient for the community to feedback translation content, because in fact many developers are willing to do so.